# How to loop through multiple array into single foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have below data array,I need to loop through it using single foreach function.
I need [A],[B] etc as key and its values as values.

How can I do that

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [A] => TestCompany1
                    [B] => testcompany1
                    [C] => fle
                    [D] => subscription
                    [E] => google.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [A] => TestCompany2
                    [B] => testcompany2
                    [C] => eid
                    [D] => subscription
                    [E] => google.com
                )    
        )
```

I need out put without using multiple foreach (like this is what i am using now)

```
foreach($row['data'] as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $key1 => $val1) {
        $field = $val1;
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show an example of the expected output. That'd make it easier.

Comment: And how you see it? Cause key will duplicate each other: A,B..A,B etc.
Give sample of result

Comment: If the key values are like 0,1,2,3..that will work

Comment: Makes no sense. Show us how you want the output array to look like.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: foreach ($data as $item) var_dump($item['A'], $item['B']); // what wrong?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator - Explained what I need

Comment: @Deep It should be $item[0] and $item[1].

Comment: @RaxWeber Ok: $item[0]['A']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using below code.

```
$data = array();
foreach($row['data'] as $val) {

  $data['field1'][] = $val['A']; 
  $data['field2'][] = $val['B']; 
  $data['field3'][] = $val['C']; 
  $data['field4'][] = $val['D']; 
  $data['field5'][] = $val['E']; 
}
```

Where I used single foreach function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
foreach($row['data'] as $val) {
    echo $val[0]['A']; // TestCompany1;
    echo $val[1]['A']; // TestCompany2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess what you need.The result is like:

```
A = [TestCompany1, TestCompany2]
B = [testcompany1, testcompany2]
C = [fle, eid]
D =>subscription
E =>google.com
```

say:

```
$array[0] = array(
        'A'=>'TestCompany1',
        'B'=>'testCompany1',
        'C'=>'fle',
        'D'=>'subscription',
        'E'=>'google.com'
);

$array[1] = array(
        'A'=>'TestCompany2',
        'B'=>'testCompany2',
        'C'=>'eid',
        'D'=>'subscription',
        'E'=>'google.com'
);
```

You can use:
$result = array_merge_recursive($array[0], $array[1]);
and then convert or $result.